# Trying to improve Encode::decode warning message: Segfault in $SIG{__WARN__} handler

Tags: perl

I am trying to improve the warning message issued by [`Encode::decode()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Encode#FB_WARN). Instead of printing the name of the module and the line number in the module, I would like it to print the name of the file being read and the line number in that file where the malformed data was found. To a developer, the origial message can be useful, but to an end user not familiar with Perl, it is probably quite meaningless. The end user would probably rather like to know which file is giving the problem.

I first tried to solve this using a [`$SIG{__WARN__}`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/warn.html) handler (which is probably not a good idea), but I get a segfault. Probably a silly mistake, but I could not figure it out:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

use Encode ();

binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';
binmode STDERR, ':utf8';

my $fn = 'test.txt';
write_test_file( $fn );

# Try to improve the Encode::FB_WARN fallback warning message :
#
#   utf8 "\xE5" does not map to Unicode at <module_name> line xx
#
# Rather we would like the warning to print the filename and the line number:
#
#   utf8 "\xE5" does not map to Unicode at line xx of file <filename>.

my $str = '';
open ( my $fh, "<:encoding(utf-8)", $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
{
    local $SIG{__WARN__} = sub { my_warn_handler( $fn, $_[0] ) }; 
    $str = do { local $/; <$fh> };
}
close $fh;
say "Read string: '$str'";

sub my_warn_handler {
    my ( $fn, $msg ) = @_;

    if ( $msg =~ /\Qdoes not map to Unicode\E/ ) {
        recover_line_number_and_char_pos( $fn, $msg );
    }
    else {
        warn $msg;
    }
}

sub recover_line_number_and_char_pos {
    my ( $fn, $err_msg ) = @_;

    chomp $err_msg;
    $err_msg =~ s/(line \d+)\.$/$1/;  # Remove period at end of sentence.
    open ( $fh, "<:raw", $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
    my $raw_data = do { local $/; <$fh> };
    close $fh;
    my $str = Encode::decode( 'utf-8', $raw_data, Encode::FB_QUIET );
    my ($header, $last_line) = $str =~ /^(.*\n)([^\n]*)$/s; 
    my $line_no = $str =~ tr/\n//;
    ++$line_no;
    my $pos = ( length $last_line ) + 1;
    warn "$err_msg, in file '$fn' (line: $line_no, pos: $pos)\n";
}

sub write_test_file {
    my ( $fn ) = @_;

    my $bytes = "Hello\nA\x{E5}\x{61}";  # 2 lines ending in iso 8859-1: åa
    open ( my $fh, '>:raw', $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
    print $fh $bytes;
    close $fh;
}
```

Output:

```
utf8 "\xE5" does not map to Unicode at ./p.pl line 27
, in file 'test.txt' (line: 2, pos: 2)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Perhaps my_warn_handler goes into infinite recursion. Try putting `local $SIG{__WARN__};` inside my_warn_handler to restore the default behavior?

Comment: @Waxrat According to the [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/warn.html), that should not happen: *"Most handlers must therefore arrange to actually display the warnings that they are not prepared to deal with, by calling warn again in the handler. Note that this is quite safe and will not produce an endless loop, since \__WARN\__ hooks are not called from inside one."*

Comment: Think I found the error: I forgot to declare the `$fh` as lexical within the handler. So it reopens the lexical `$fh` defined in the enclosing scope and later closes that handle. So this is probably causing some confusion to `Encode::decode()`..

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to locate where the warning fires, with un-buffered `sysread`

```
use warnings;
use strict;

binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';
binmode STDERR, ':utf8';

my $file = 'test.txt';
open my $fh, "<:encoding(UTF-8)", $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";

$SIG{__WARN__} = sub { print "\t==> WARN: @_" };

my $char_cnt = 0;    
my $char;

while (sysread($fh, $char, 1)) {
    ++$char_cnt;
    print "$char ($char_cnt)\n";
}
```

The file `test.txt` was written by the posted program, except that I had to add to it to reproduce the behavior -- it runs without warnings on v5.10 and v5.16. I added `\x{234234}` to the end.  The line number can be tracked with `$char =~ /\n/`.

The `sysread` returns `undef` on error. It can be moved into the body of `while (1)` to allow reads to continue and catch all warnings, breaking out on `0` (returned on EOF).

This prints

```
H (1)
e (2)
l (3)
l (4)
o (5)

 (6)
A (7)
å (8)
a (9)
        ==> WARN: Code point 0x234234 is not Unicode, may not be portable at ...
 (10)
```

While this does catch the character warned about, re-reading the file using `Encode` may well be better than reaching for `sysread`, in particular if `sysread` uses `Encode`.

However, Perl is `utf8` internally and I am not sure that `sysread` needs `Encode`.

Note. The page for [sysread](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sysread.html) supports its use on data with encoding layers

> Note that if the filehandle has been marked as `:utf8` Unicode
>   characters are read instead of bytes (the LENGTH, OFFSET, and the
>   return value of `sysread` are in Unicode characters). The
>   `:encoding(...)` layer implicitly introduces the `:utf8` layer.
>   See `binmode`, `open`, and the `open` pragma.

---

**Note**   Apparently, things have moved on and after a certain version **`sysread` does not support encoding layers**.  The link above, while for an older version (v5.10 for one) indeed shows what is quoted, with a newer version tells us that there'll be an exception.

Comment: Interesting. I have not checked the source yet, but according to [PerlIO::encoding](http://perldoc.perl.org/PerlIO/encoding.html) it seems that `readline` will call `Encode::decode()`, so the warning should come from `Encode` then?

Comment: @HåkonHægland The `sysread` uses `read(2)`, it's about the lowest level. The docs do say that it reads unicode if the filehandle is "marked" `:utf8` but I don't know that it would use `Encode` ...? May remove the first sentence until I clear it up.  My main point was to locate the warning by 'direct' reading.

Comment: @HåkonHægland  This is indeed tricky and I am not sure whether `sysread` needs/uses `Encode`.  I adjusted the answer accordingly.

Comment: Using `sysread` on a handle with encoding layers sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: @melpomene  The page for `sysread` specifically supports it, in the closing paragraph.

Comment: @zdim I suspect that's more of an implementation accident than an intentional feature. It's also unclear: For example, `:encoding(latin-9)` shouldn't really be doing anything with Unicode.

Comment: @melpomene  May be. However, internally it is all utf8 so low level reads need to support that.  I was trying to locate the warning and didn't think of `sysread` resorting to `Encode`, and I don't know that it does. If the warning does come from reading this directly than I'd rather catch it there.