# Perl warns about invalid encoding even if I don't read the problematic data from the file

Tags: perl, file-io, character-encoding

I'm trying to read lines from the first part of a file that contains a text header encoded in the [cp1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) encoding, and contains binary data after a specific keyword.

#### Problem

Perl warns about invalid encoding  in parts of the file I never read. I've created an example in two files to demonstrate the problem.

Contents of *linebug.pl*:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use 5.028;
use strict;
use warnings;
open( my $fh, "<:encoding(cp1252)", "testfile" );
while( <$fh> ) {
    print;
    last if /Last/;
}
```

Hexdump of *testfile*, where the byte `0x81` right after the text *Wrong* is purposefully added because it is not a valid cp1252 codepoint:

```
46 69 72 73 74 0a         |First.|
4c 61 73 74 0a            |Last.|
42 75 66 66 65 72 0a      |Buffer.|
57 72 6f 6e 67 81 0a      |Wrong..|
```

The third line *Buffer* is just there to make it clear that I do not read too far. It is a valid line between the last line I read, and the "binary" data.

Here is the output showing that I only ever read two lines, but perl still emits a warning:

```
user@host$ perl linebug.pl
cp1252 "\x81" does not map to Unicode at ./linebug.pl line 6.
First
Last
user@host$
```

As can be seen, my program reads and prints the first two lines, and then exits. It should never try to read and interpret anything else, but I still get the warning about `\x81` not mapping to Unicode.

#### Questions

- Why does it warn? I'm not reading the line. A hunch tells me it's trying to read ahead, but why would it try to decode?
- Is there a workaround, or a better way to handle files where the encoding changes from one section to another?

I still want the warning when reading the initial lines, in case the file is damaged.

Comment: Presumably it does encoding conversion when reading from the file into an internal buffer, not when data is actually returned to the program from that buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Files don't have a concept of lines; they are just streams of bytes. Perl must request a number of bytes from the file from the OS and figure out where the line ends in order to return a line to the program.

Perl could request a single byte at a time from the OS until it has a full line, but that would be very inefficient. There's a lot of overhead involved in making system calls. As such, Perl requests 8 KiB at a time.

Then, the raw data must be decoded before Perl can determine where the line ends, because a raw `0A` doesn't necessarily indicate the end of the line.

Similarly to why one doesn't read from a file one byte at a time, asking the decoder to decode just the next character would be inefficient. There is overhead involved every time you start and stop decoding. As such, Perl decodes all the data it reads as it reads it.

So that means that Perl both reads and decodes more than it returns to the program.

---

The solution is to treat the file as binary (because it's not really a text file if the encoding changes by section) and do the decoding yourself.

If you're dealing with a single-byte encoding like cp1252, you can continue using `readline` (aka `<$fh>`). However, instead of telling Perl to search for the Code Point of Line Feed (`0A`), you need to set `$/` to the encoding of the Code Point. As it happens, that's also `0A` for cp1252, so no change is needed.

```
use Encode qw( decode );

open( my $fh, "<:raw", $qfn )
   or die( "Can't open \"$qfn\": $!\n" );

while( <$fh> ) {
    $_ = decode( 'cp1252', $_ );      # :encoding(cp1252)
    s/\r\n\z/\n/ if $^O eq 'Win32';   # :crlf
    print;
    last if /Last/;
}
```

If you weren't using a single-byte encoding, you might have to switch to using `read`. (You could keep using `readline` for UTF-8 because of the way it's designed.) When using `read`, the exact solution depends on a few specifics (that pertain to determining how much to read and how much to decode).

Answer (score 1):

Perl reads from the file in 8 KiB chunks, so way more than a line is read at a time. Data is decoded right as it is read (since the stream must be decoded to find the line endings), so an unexpected encoding is noticed and warned about.

One way to deal with this: use non-buffered reads, via [sysread](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sysread.html), and read smaller chunks at a time.

Count characters read and once you run into that spot you can back up and continue reading character at a time, again counting them, so to detect the exact place. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41377538/4653379) for a working example of identifying the spot where a warning is fired.

In order to be able to stop there you'll likely want to throw a `die` out of a `$SIG{__WARN__}` handler, and have all that code in `eval`.  This will allow you to stop at the place where the warning comes from and have control back.

As you've read right up to that spot, you can then re-open the file in the encoding suitable for the rest of the file and seek to that spot and read the rest.

I can't write and test all that right now, hopefully this helps.

Comment: Re "*use non-buffered reads, via sysread, and read smaller chunks at a time.*", This is all wrong. The solution isn't switching to unbuffered; the solution is switching to doing the decoding yourself. You can continue to use buffered I/O (`read` and even `readline` aka `<>`), but decoding on what you should be decoding. The chunk size is irrelevant.

Comment: @ikegami You mean to read (with `:raw` or silence warnings) and then go through it and (Encode::)decode (quietly)?  OK, I've seen that.  Will still have some work to do to detect where things change etc.  But why is this "all wrong"?  Thank you for the edit.

Comment: Re "*You mean to read (with :raw or silence warnings) and then go through it and (Encode::)decode (quietly)?*", Yes (except for silence warning part). Isn't that what you meant? (After all, you can't use `:encoding` with `sysread`)

Comment: Re "*But why is this "all wrong"?*", It's irrelevant whether the read is buffered or not. Switching to unbuffered reads doesn't help; it's switching to doing the decoding yourself that does.

Comment: @ikegami With unbuffered reads it doesn't (attempt to) decode further than what I ask it to read, so with smaller reads I can better locate the spot where the encoding changes. (However, now I see that that happens "_after a specific keyword_", which i somehow missed and thought that the code needs to discover that location).  I do like a solution that decodes manually as it goes, of course.

Comment: @ikegami "_can't use `:encoding` with `sysread`_"  -- why not? I think that the end of the `sysread` page implies that it's OK?

Comment: Re "*With unbuffered reads it doesn't (attempt to) decode further than what I ask it to read*", Not quite. With unbuffered reads it doesn't (attempt to) decode further than what I ask it to read because you can't use `:encoding` with unbuffered reads. The solution isn't "*remove `:encoding` and use unbuffered reads*", the solution is just "*remove `:encoding`*".

Comment: You definitely can't use if for multi-byte encodings (like UTF-8) because there's no buffer to store partially decoded characters. But it doesn't work for cp1252 either because the length is a length *in bytes*. Try `perl -e'print chr(0x80)' | perl -MData::Dumper -e'binmode(STDIN, ":encoding(cp1252)"); read(\*STDIN, $buf, 1); $Data::Dumper::Useqq=1; print(Dumper($buf))'`, then swtich to `read` to `sysread`.

Comment: The [docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perlfunc.pod#sysread-FILEHANDLE,SCALAR,LENGTH,OFFSET) say "*Note that if the filehandle has been marked as `:utf8`, `sysread` will throw an exception. The `:encoding(...)` layer implicitly introduces the `:utf8` layer.*". The exception is new. The fixed docs is new. The fact that it doesn't work is not new.

Comment: @ikegami yeah, I'll have to look into that way better (you mean that with `sysread` I can't read encodings other than ASCII?).  As for the docs, what it says now to me means that UTF-8 does work, and it _may_ imply that other encodings would (but it doesn't say so, only mentions `:encoding`).  If that's wrong than all this is off to start with of course.

Comment: @ikegami "_The docs say..._" --- ah, that's news to me.  I got to 5.26 (now i see) with perldoc. I remember using it (5.10 perhaps) and it worked ... or so it seemed. (I may have missed to notice that it didn't)

Comment: Re "*you mean that with sysread I can't read encodings other than ASCII?*", With sysread, you can only read bytes. If those bytes represent text encoded using ASCII and you pass them to a sub that expected text using ASCII (or a superset of ASCII such as ISO-8859-* or UTF-8), you're good.

Comment: @ikegami "_With sysread, you can only read bytes_" -- um, yes, right of course. I see what you meant

Comment: [You just failed to notice.](https://pastebin.com/hCT1i8xc) It literally produces a corrupt scalar.

Comment: @ikegami Thank you again, I'll have to look into this more carefully.  (Regardless of that, as I said, I like the approach to read raw and decode as it goes, +1 for your post)

Comment: Related reads: [What is the difference between `read` and `sysread`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36315124/589924) and [`:encoding(UTF-8)` vs `:encoding(utf8)` vs `:utf8`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49040165/589924)

Comment: @ikegami "_Related reads_" -- oh yes, well aware of those :)  Thanks for bringing them up, should go through it again (for example, I apparently never took notice of "_`sysread` doesn't support PerlIO layers_")

Comment: @ikegami "_Just failed to notice_" -- that `\x80` (really) `does not map to Unicode` (I get that when I change `sysread` to `read` and encoding to UTF-8), so it doesn't show that encoding fails?  But I see the point of course.  Thank you

Comment: I don't get `\x80 does not map to Unicode`. Nor should you. 80[cp1252] maps to 20AC[Unicode] (€)

Comment: I change encoding in your example to UTF-8 (since that's what I believed should work for sure)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. You gave bad data, and you got a message saying the decode failed.

Comment: @ikegami (I meant that it's not valid unicode anyway so of course it fails to decode when UTF-8 encoding is set)  But i should look into this way more, before talking.  thank you again